# Creating a block of navigation tabs for a node's content

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have a content type that has quite a large amount of content in each node, so I've decided to create a set of tabs that will house the content in a more user friendly manner.

Currently, I am using the 'field group' module to organise the content into tabs, which works fine. However, I need to move the tabs only (the ul and li's) to a region on the page (the right sidebar) which is separate to where the actual content displays.

I played around with 'display suite' to try and achieve this, but to my knowledge you can't actually separate the tabbed navigation as a block from the content it displays and place it in a region of your choosing.

I also saw that there is the module 'fieldgroup menu' that almost does what I want, however it seems that this module actually generates separate pages (URL's) for each tab. This isn't what I need to achieve. I need it to function exactly as it does using just 'field group' vertical tabs, but to be able to place the tabs only into a different region and for the content to display all on the same page within different tabs.

Is there another way that I should be approaching this?

Answer (score 0):

You should try with views and create blocks for each of the field groups.

Comment: I've played around a bit with views, but I can't seem to separate the 'field group' tabs from the content they display. I've also tried to render the tabs in the node template but can't target them specifically.